# In Django, can you not use a string join on a ManyToManyField? Is ManyToMany not just a list?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in my Django project:

- Match
- Player

Match has a ManyToMany property pointing at players, so that multiple players can compete in a match. I'd like to return an informative object name in the Django admin, something like "Richard Henry vs John Doe", by using a join on the players' full names. However the following fails:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, verbose_name='Competitors')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " vs ".join(self.players)
```

Are ManyToManyFields not just lists? Why can't I join them? Any input is appreciated. Here's my player model, incase that helps:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.full_name
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: I just discovered that I can use `self.players.list_display` to have this returned as a list. I'm no longer spat a traceback, but for some reason the `__unicode__` name now returns `None`. Any idea why that would be?

**Edit 2**: Changed code:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, verbose_name='Competitors')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return " vs ".join(self.players.list_display)
```

Comment: S.Lott: Just posted 'edit 2'.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is:

```
return " vs ".join(p.full_name for p in self.players.all())
```

Note: Sorry for bringing this back -- gravedigger :-)

Answer (score 6):

"Are ManyToManyFields not just lists?"

No.

They're [querysets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference).  Which are list-like, but not actually lists.

Do this.

```
return " vs ".join(list(self.players))
```

The list function will force evaluation of the query set and return a list object.

Answer (score 0):

No, ManyToManyField is not a list, it's just a single key and there will be one Match instance for each player in the match.

You don't want to do a query in the __unicode__() method because it will most likely be a big performance hit.   Just display the X vs. Y in your template.