# Correctly returning object through Many to Many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

My objective is to display a readable list of Articles that belong to my user named 'Admin'

In other words, give me all articles that Admin owns. In my sample data I have Admin owning 1 article.

Problem: When I return the object, its a completely unreadable and unhelpful representation of this object. I'm thinking of adding a **unicode**() method to my model here but I don't know how!!

*Model.py:*

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Article (models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    keywords = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class ArticleUserOwnership (models.Model):
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

-- you can see here I'm hooking into the admin user table

*Views.py:*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from GeorgiaArticleManager.models import Article, ArticleUserOwnership
from django.shortcuts import render

def myarticles(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():

    # articles of admin with id= 1
    my_articles = ArticleUserOwnership.objects.filter(user=1)
    context = {'my_articles': my_articles}


return render(request, 'template/myview.html', context)
```

*myview.html:*

```
ul
{% for ArticleUserOwnership in my_articles %}
li{{ ArticleUserOwnership }}/li
{% endfor %}
/ul
```

**In summary of above:** 
ArticleUserOwnership.objects.filter(user=1) returns me an object that when I display it on myview.html, I just get 'ArticleUserOwnership object'. I'm sure this is the correct returned object but, I'd like to see returned Article.question. For example Admin owns 'test title 1' and I'd like to see this article question field displayed properly.

Comment: You can use .join() and format the string anyway you like, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582237/in-django-can-you-not-use-a-string-join-on-a-manytomanyfield-is-manytomany-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_articles = ArticleUserOwnership.objects.filter(user=1)
```

gives you a list of `ArticleUserOwnership` instances. If you want of list of articles try this instead:

```
auo = ArticleUserOwnership.objects.get(user=1)  # could raise DoesNotExist
my_articles = auo.article.all()  # you should rename this field 'articles'
```

However, that `ArticleUserOwnership` model doesn't really make sense, my guess is that what you're really trying to do is this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Article (models.Model): 
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    keywords = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='owned_articles')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```

You would then access your data like so:

```
my_articles = user.owned_articles.all()
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for examples of how to use `ManyToManyFields`.

Comment: Hmm I got the following output for my_articles: "django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f77840e7150" No luck.

Comment: I forgot the `.all()`, try `my_articles = auo.article.all()`. I also edited the answer to make a broader suggestion.

Comment: The replacement model for ArticleUserOwnsership in your answer makes way more sense. Thank you. I'm going to run with this and let you know.

Comment: Happy to help. It seems like you were trying to manually create the table mapping users and articles, like you'd do in SQL. The important thing to remember is that Django creates that table for you automatically when you declare a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Woohoo this works - I've updated my models and got things running. I'm using the following code to get a list of the articles my admin owns. `b = User.objects.get(id=1) b.owned_articles.all()`. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class ArticleUserOwnership (models.Model):
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.article
```

OR

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.article.question
```

Comment: No luck got this error: Exception Value:  

'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'question'